# Personalize colored-man-pages zsh plugin colors

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just installed the [colored-man-pages](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/colored-man-pages) zsh plugin.

It works well, but I have an ugly color output on the bottom message:

[image]

What is the proper way to personalize the color of the plugins without overwriting everything? It seems the color are set up directly during the [plugin activation](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/c5272bdd7b0ebc812f3ec4a28378102a26eb77e7/plugins/colored-man-pages/colored-man-pages.plugin.zsh#L21-L27).

Or maybe it's a bug with my system, fixable with an another way? Indeed, it looks weird to have this default unreadable color output.

I run under Ubuntu 18.10 and gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of man pages (`groff`) doesn't allow colors explicitly, but utilizes a few text decorations like bold or underlines, which in turn can be re-interpreted by a viewer to show colors. And this is exactly what linked plugin is doing, so I suggest to remove this plugin and instead set the colors directly in `.zshrc` via `LESS_TERMCAP` variables (I assume you are using `less` as you `man` pager and so does this plugin).

Here is the list of variables with description:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\e[6m'          # begin blinking
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[34m'         # begin bold
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[4;32m'       # begin underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[1;33;41m'    # begin standout-mode - info box
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[m'           # end mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[m'           # end underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[m'           # end standout-mode
```

The list of color codes can be found with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "PALETTE OF 8 COLORS (bold, high intensity, normal, faint)"
for i in {30..37}; do printf "\e[1;${i}m1;%-2s      \e[m" "$i"; done; echo
for i in {90..97}; do printf "\e[${i}m%+4s      \e[m" "$i"; done; echo
for i in {30..37}; do printf "\e[${i}m%+4s      \e[m" "$i"; done; echo
for i in {30..37}; do printf "\e[2;${i}m2;%-2s      \e[m" "$i"; done;

echo -e "\n\n\nPALETTE OF 256 COLORS (only normal)"
j=8
for i in {0..255}; do
    [[ $i = 16 ]] && j=6
    [[ $i = 232 ]] && j=8
    printf "\e[38;5;${i}m38;5;%-4s\e[m" "${i}"
    (( i>15 && i<232 )) && printf "\e[52C\e[1;38;5;${i}m1;38;5;%-4s\e[52C\e[m\e[2;38;5;${i}m2;38;5;%-4s\e[m\e[126D" "${i}" "${i}"
    [[ $(( $(( $i - 15 )) % $j )) = 0 ]] && echo
    [[ $(( $(( $i - 15 )) % $(( $j * 6 )) )) = 0 ]] && echo
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Well, I would prefer a way to not override all the default colors settings, but it's not a painful thing after all.
Thanks for the detailed explanation by the way, I appreciate it. :-)
If no less intrusive option is proposed, I'll select it as best answer.

Comment: @Soullivaneuh there is no other way to set colors than that and linked plugin does exactly the same (see its source) + some extra `nroff` stuff for solaris. BTW, your 'ugly' blue line comes from `LESS_TERMCAP_so` variable, so perhaps for you it is enough to change only this one.

Comment: Which variable would be matching for highlight color for when I search a word in `man`?

Comment: @alper Also `LESS_TERMCAP_so`.

Comment: I was able to come up with coloring by trial and error for the `\e[1;33;41m'`

Answer (score 0):

The given solution is quite elegant. I wish the official Oh My ZSH wiki 
[ohmyzsh/plugins/colored-man-pages/](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/colored-man-pages) where there is no list of colors or of the items in the array `less_termcap`. Here is the content of ##Customization with just one small example:

> The plugin declares global associative array `less_termcap`, which maps termcap capabilities to escape sequences for the `less` pager. This mapping can be further customized by the user after the plugin is loaded. Check out sources for more.
>
> For example: `less_termcap[md]` maps to `LESS_TERMCAP_md` which is the escape sequence that tells `less` how to print something in bold. It's currently shown in bold red, but if you want to change it, you can redefine `less_termcap[md]` in your zshrc file, after OMZ is sourced:
>
> ```
> less_termcap[md]="${fg_bold[blue]}" # this tells less to print bold text in bold blue
> ```

And I guess you could experiment more with all **termcap**

```
# mb       start blink
# md       start bold
# me       turn off bold, blink and underline
# so       start standout (reverse video)
# se       stop standout
# us       start underline
# ue       stop underline
```

---

---

#### NOTE

But if you actually don't want spending time by trial and error, that one line could be more than enough

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/416945)